# how to generate gRPC stubs for python from gradle

Tags: python, gradle, grpc

Is there a way to generate python grpc stubs from gradle?

Typically examples I've seen are running python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../protos --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/helloworld.proto manually rather than from gradle which doesn't make sense.

Thanks.